# HomeScreen Widget - Updates Only When New Instance

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget on my home screen responsible for showing the current song and is ment to be able to switch songs and such... Currently I am only trying to implement its ability to show current song.

I've attached all relevant code... with comments. There is NO ERROR THROWN and it DOES UPDATE but ONLY WHEN I CREATE A NEW INSTANCE OF THE WIDGET ON HOMESCREEN. To explain if I had a widget I put there before I start playing a song, it would say "Not Playing" when I start playing a song from my application it will update but will still keep saying "Not Playing" and then when I create a new widget of the same type and place down it will stay the updated information while the old one still would say not playing. This continues if I change song the one i jsut placed would not update nor would the one that siad not playing but creating a new one will show the update...

**MainActivity Receiving call from MusicManager and sending for widget update (works?)**

```
 public MusicManager musicManager = MusicManager.getInstance(new MusicManager.MediaplayerUpdateInterface() {

    public void updateUI(int type) {
        updateMediaplayerViews(type);
    }
});

public void updateMediaplayerViews(int type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 0:
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("value? "+(musicManager.getCurrentTimeBAR()/musicManager.getSongLengthBAR()));
                    SongListFragment.musicManagerProgress.setProgress((int)((musicManager.getCurrentTimeBAR()/(double)musicManager.getSongLengthBAR())*100));
                    SongListFragment.musicManagerCurrent.setText(musicManager.getCurrentTime());
                    if(!SongListFragment.hasSetImage) {
                        SongListFragment.musicManagerTotal.setText(musicManager.getSongLength());
                        SongListFragment.musicManagerSongName.setText(musicManager.getCurrentSongInfo().getName().length() > 22 ? musicManager.getCurrentSongInfo().getName().substring(0, 19) + "..." : musicManager.getCurrentSongInfo().getName());
                        new DownloadListAdapter.DownloadImageTask(SongListFragment.musicManagerImageView).execute(musicManager.getCurrentSongInfo().getImgurl());
                        SongListFragment.hasSetImage = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
        case 10:
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TrinityWidget.class);
                    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
                    int[] ids = {TrinityWidget.widgetId};
                    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
                    getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

**MusicManager Sending for Update (Works)**

```
    public static MusicManager myInstance;

private boolean songHasChanged;
public MusicManager(MediaplayerUpdateInterface inter) {
    this.player = new MediaPlayer();
    this.uiUpdateInterface = inter;
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if(songHasChanged) {
                    uiUpdateInterface.updateUI(10);
                    songHasChanged = false;
                }
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    uiUpdateInterface.updateUI(0);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public static MusicManager getInstance(MediaplayerUpdateInterface inter) {
    if (myInstance == null)
        return myInstance = new MusicManager(inter);
    else
        return myInstance;
}
```

**Widget code (problematic?)**

```
public class TrinityWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static boolean needsImage;
public static final int widgetId = 188772;
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
    }
}


// the below method is where it updates i believe it does work but the updates don't apply until A new widget is created?

public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                   int appWidgetId) {
    try {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.trinity_widget);

        if (MusicManager.myInstance != null) {
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetsongtext, MusicManager.myInstance.getCurrentSongInfo() != null ? MusicManager.myInstance.getCurrentSongInfo().getName() : "Not Playing");
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetartisttext, MusicManager.myInstance.getCurrentSongInfo() != null ? MusicManager.myInstance.getCurrentSongInfo().getArtist() : "Not Playing");
        } else {
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetsongtext, "Not Playing");
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetartisttext, "Not Playing");
        }
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {

}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}

}
```

Basically it looks like all widgets do not update until i recreate them manually. and they new ones are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was not updating the right ID for some reason... Either way I am now updated based on class. like the below

```
ComponentName projectWidget = new ComponentName(context, TrinityWidget.class);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(projectWidget, views);
```